# In an equilateral triangle $\triangle ABC$, $AD$ is drawn perpendicular to $BC$ meeting $BC$ in $D$. Prove that $AD^{2} = 3 BD^{2}$.

Tags: triangles

In an equilateral triangle $\triangle ABC$, $AD$ is drawn perpendicular to $BC$ meeting $BC$ in $D$. Prove that $AD^{2} = 3 BD^{2}$.

Comment: Hint: Triangle $ABD$ is a $30$-$60$-$90$ right triangle.

Comment: https://brilliant.org/wiki/properties-of-equilateral-triangles/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fairly simple.

Note that $ABD$ is a right triangle, thus:

$AB^2=AD^2+BD^2$

You have also $BC=AB=2BD$

Then $4BD^2=AD^2+BD^2$

That is

$AD^2=3BD^2$

Answer (score 0):

we have applying the Pythagorean theorem $$AD^2+BD^2=AB^2$$ and $$BD=\frac{1}{2}AB$$
can you finish?

Comment: Yeah! Thanks for ur help

Comment: have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Just some trigonometry:
$$\tan\frac\pi3=\sqrt 3=\frac{AD}{BD}.$$